# Is it possible to send curl request with Flutter's http package?

Tags: curl, flutter, https

I'm pretty new to Flutter and to API http/curl requests and json responses. I'm looking at the http package and I'm wandering if it would be the right option to send also curl requests.
 In the API docs (http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.22.0/api/?language=cURL#general-options) I see that the request has to have this form:
 `GET /{service}/{version}/{profile}/{coordinates}[.{format}]?option=value&option=value`
and a given example is `curl 'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?exclude=motorway'` and I'm pretty confident I can put together the requests I need but I'm not sure on how to send them.

In the http package example it seems to me that I could just pass `'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?exclude=motorway'` as the url, am I right or how would I go sending it?

Many thanks for your time and help.

My function:

```
import 'package:curl/curl.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';


void postRequest() async {
    print('postRequest called');

    // ERROR The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
    final curlRequest = new Request("GET",
        "http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?exclude=motorway");

    // working properly
    final request =
        'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?exclude=motorway';

    // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
    var response = await get(request);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      print('$jsonResponse');
    } else {
      print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you check curl package? https://pub.dev/packages/curl

Comment: @taha_emin yes, as I saw it suggested in another question, but from the example is not clear to me how to use it.. I see `final req1 = new Request("GET", "http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?exclude=motorway");`would be the way to obtain `'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?exclude=motorway'` but how does it get sent?

Comment: curl is an app or library used for sending http requests.

Comment: @MisirJafarov so my 3rd example would be correct?

Comment: @Vincenzo   you just could write `var response = await get("http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?exclude=motorway");`

Comment: @MisirJafarov yes indeed, I was trying out the 'Curl' package way and it throws an error.. I can't understand how to use that..
I did try just passing the url as a string and get the response .. it worked..
Do you know how to use the `Curl`package?

Comment: @Vincenzo I'd prefer using `http` package instead of `curl`. Because It was recommended by flutter team too. If you like to look for alternatives try, `Duo`.

Comment: @MisirJafarov no no I don't need it .. I'm cool with http as it works..
Thanks for the help.